# Type of investments to protect value

Tags: starting-out-investing

I live in Argentina where there are a lot of inflation, between 40% and 60% a year in last years, so my question it's what kind of assets should I study to protect value? I'm beginner in investments but as far as I know for this goal I should think in long term and low volatility assets. What do you think about that? Can someone give any advice for where could I start with investments or what approach should I have for this goal?

Comment: Real estate is the standard answer for hedging against inflation.  Maybe REITs (Real Estate Investment Trusts, if they exist in Argentina) are a good idea.

Answer (score -3):

First of all you should convert your money into gold because that will reduce it from the further decrease and also give you reasonable return.